# I want Access to automatically enter a very specific data in a new field I created, the data will come from an existing field in the same table

Tags: database, ms-access, expression, record, ms-access-2016

This is related to MS Access 2016. I have a field called **Name** in which I have a long string. Every record in the **Name** field has an year mentioned in it along with some string. The year is always mentioned in paranthesis for example.

The story of a dead girl (1987) by Jack Ding

3 days of necro (2007) on water

etc...

I want to create another field called **year** in which I just want to add the year of that record automatically. I also want to delete everything after and including the year information in the **Name** field from every record. so in the above example I want to delete the string '*(1987) by Jack Ding*' and '*(2007) on water*' from the respective records.

I know I can just type it or Copy/Paste info from **Name** to **Year** but I have 4000+ records and I want to build a Query or Expression or Macro or whatever (I seriously don't know what) that will take only the year Info from **Name** field and put it in **Year** field automatically and delete everything after the year that is mentioned in the **Name** field (including the year itself)

Any Help will be appericiated

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in sql or vba, but this expression should output the correct value assuming there is only one open parentheses in any single string (though there are workarounds if there are multiple):

`MID([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"(")+1,4)`

The `InStr` function searches `[Name]` for the **first** open parentheses and returns the position of that character in the string. `Mid` extracts a specified number of characters from a string, but you have to tell it where in the string to start. Nesting them together, `InStr` tells `Mid` to start extracting at the position of the first open paren, +1 character, which should be the first digit of the year. Then `Mid` takes the 4 digits from that starting point and returns the string.

If your `year` field is a date data type, you may improve the expression by wrapping it in `CDate` which converts a string to a date data type.

You can write an `UPDATE` query using this expression to add the year for each record into the `year` field in the table:

```
UPDATE MyTableWithName&Year
SET Year = CDate(MID([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"(")+1,4));
```

**EDIT:** I missed the delete portion of your question. As you can see, `InStr` can be used to identify the position of your first open parens, so it can be used the same way with the `LEFT` function to truncate everything but the title. So the expression would be something like:

`LEFT([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"(")-1)`

You can then use that in a second `UPDATE` query (I would do these consecutively, since we don't want to truncate before the year is extracted) SQL code would be:

```
UPDATE MyTableWithName&Year
SET Name = LEFT([Name],InStr(1,[Name],"(")-1);
```